# Add hidden form field for lead to account relationship using Web-To-Lead

Tags: custom-field, web-to-case

I have a custom field on my Lead object that specifies an account for the lead referral. I would like to provide the ID for this account on Web-To-Lead form submission but it does not appear to work.

The field does not appear in the Salesforce W2L form builder field selection list.

I have tried finding the custom field ID from the URL when editing the custom field and created a hidden field for that. The lead submits but is missing that information in the created lead record.

Does anyone know if it is even possible to provide object lookup field IDs bu hidden fields in W2L forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't allow custom lookup fields on web-to-lead forms, even as hidden fields.  You could try passing the ID in a hidden text field instead and using Process Builder + Flow or an Apex trigger to populate the lookup field from this,